# How can I know the list of isolated cpu for the current running kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, system-calls

So far my application requests the list of isolated cpu in its configuration file. Then it uses `pthread_setaffinity_np()` in order to force running on that kind of cpu. Usually the guy who made the configuration file goes into the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and pick the correct entry, in order to know what is the current list of isolated cpu.

```
title CentOS (2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel ... isolcpus=4-15
```

So, I would like to avoid the guy to have to enter that list manually in the configuration file. Is there a possible way for my application to get that list *programatically*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only in a very backwards way - /proc/cmdline has the current kernel command line which you can parse to get the parameters the kernel was booted with, including isolcpus

Answer (score 11):

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that PID 1 is bound to the non-isolated CPUs, so the list of isolated CPUs would be all CPUs minus that list.

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
... isolcpus=2-7 ...
# taskset -p 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
3
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
0-7
```

Comment: That doesn't work on my embedded system. Not sure why.